# Unexpected T_string in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I get an unexpected T_STRING error for this very commonly used Wordpress code (loop), which is the only php code so far in the file. The problem line is the `while` line, which means the `if` line is somehow involved.

```
<?php
  if (have_posts()): 
    while (have_ posts()) : the_ post()
?>
    <a href="<?php the_ permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <br>
<?php
      the_content();
    endwhile;
  endif;
?>
```

I'm a newbie with php, so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: That looks more like python to me than php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have an extra space in `have_ posts()`, `the_ post()` and `the_ permalink()`.

Comment: That was it. I can't believe I missed it!

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `the_ post()` instead of `the_post()`, which also needs to be followed by a semicolon:

```
while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

I see you made the same mistake in `have_ posts()` and `the_ permalink()` too.

Also, there's a StackExchange site specifically for WordPress online at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com that you might find particularly helpful when working on WP projects.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some spaces in unsuitable places on the following places:

```
while (have_ posts()) : the_ post()?> //should be have_posts() & the_post()

<a href="<?php the_ permalink(); ?>" //should be the_permalink()
```

Hopefully this solves your issue!